# Debug liquid tags in Octopress / Jekyll

Tags: jekyll, liquid, octopress

Any ideas how to see where liquid tags actually fail?

To be clearer, I'm having some trouble with a plugin and all I see on previewing my site is

```
Liquid Error: can’t convert Array into String
```

On my site. How do I get more debug information? Thanks

Comment: I don't use Octopress, so this is a straight question, is it possible to run just jekyll and see what errors it produces? (When it bugs out, for me, I normally see more of an error message that usually includes the file that having the problem.)

Comment: I'm not sure! I imagine it can be done, I guess I need to find out more about vanilla jekyll first. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to run rake generate with --trace for more detailed information.

```
rake generate --trace
```

Commonly, it will give exactly where the error is promoted.Then simply print some variables or  use [debugger](https://github.com/cldwalker/debugger) to debug.

This [blog](http://abop.github.io/blog/2013/05/15/debug-with-jekyll-rubygem/) may be helpful.